# Django after production deployment "No such file or directory"

Tags: django, linux, apache, ubuntu, apache2

Django test went fine in the test environment. When I went for production and typed in my ip address in the browser I get the following error snippet from the browser.

```
FileNotFoundError at /
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mainAboutUs.txt'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://139.162.136.239/
Django Version: 3.1.7
Exception Type: FileNotFoundError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mainAboutUs.txt'
Exception Location: /home/jianwu/HD_website/website/index/views.py, line 50, in importTextFile
Python Executable:  /home/jianwu/HD_website/env/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['/home/jianwu/HD_website/website',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/jianwu/HD_website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 11 Mar 2021 19:24:51 +0000
```

I have verified that the mainAboutUs.txt is located in my project folder. The views.py is located in index folder. I am serving my website using apache2.

```
(env) jianwu@django-server:~/HD_website/website$ ll
total 188
drwxrwxr-x 7 jianwu www-data   4096 Mar  7 15:48  ./
drwxrwxr-x 6 jianwu jianwu     4096 Mar  7 15:44  ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jianwu jianwu     1968 Mar  7 15:24 'aboutUs2900 2.txt'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jianwu jianwu     1968 Mar  7 12:54  aboutUs2900.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jianwu jianwu     3008 Mar  7 12:54  aboutUsNytorv.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jianwu www-data 131072 Mar  7 12:54  db.sqlite3
-rw-r--r-- 1 jianwu jianwu      168 Mar  7 15:48  emailCred.txt
drwxrwxr-x 4 jianwu jianwu     4096 Mar 11 18:42  index/
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jianwu www-data   1968 Mar  7 12:54  mainAboutUs.txt*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jianwu jianwu      663 Mar  7 12:54  manage.py*
drwxrwxr-x 2 jianwu jianwu     4096 Mar  7 12:54  __pycache__/
drwxrwxr-x 4 jianwu www-data   4096 Mar  7 12:54  static/
-rw-r--r-- 1 jianwu jianwu     8192 Mar  7 15:19  subscriptionEmail.db
drwxrwxr-x 2 jianwu jianwu     4096 Mar  7 15:44  templates/
drwxrwxr-x 4 jianwu jianwu     4096 Mar 11 18:30  website/
```

This is how my settings.py looks like

```
"""
Django settings for website project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
import json

#Load in the config file with secret information
with open('/etc/websiteConfig.json') as fileId:
    config = json.load(fileId)

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config['SECRET_KEY']

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'website.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'website.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')]
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Below is how my configuration looks like for apache2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    
    Alias /static /home/jianwu/HD_website/website/static
    <Directory /home/jianwu/HD_website/website/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /media /home/jianwu/HD_website/website/static/media
        <Directory /home/jianwu/HD_website/website/static/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

    <Directory /home/jianwu/HD_website/website/website>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/jianwu/HD_website/website/website/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/jianwu/HD_website/website python-home=/home/jianwu/HD_website/env
    WSGIProcessGroup django_app
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: I suspect that the problem is because of you edited files in Windows and your prod is Linux. And sometimes it append some unknown characters